# PLS help to fix SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

The SPARQL query below throws errors. What's wrong? Protege syay that there's a lexical error at line 1, column 8, Encountered " " (32), after : "private"

```
private static ResultSet getСontNameFirst(OntModel model, string nameWord) { 
    String queryString = String.format(
    "PREFIX wordnet:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/wordnet.owl#> " +
    "SELECT ?word " +
    "WHERE { " +
    " ?%s wordnet:?pre ?subject " +
    " { SELECT DISTINCT ?pre WHERE { " +
    " ?word wordnet:?pre ?otherword " + "
    } }" +
    " OPTIONAL { ?%s wordnet:?pre ?word}" +
    "}", nameWord);
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query); 
    ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: what is `wordnet:?pre` in your opinion? I mean, it must be a valid RDF predicate and not a mixture of a prefixed URI and a variable.

Comment: If I run only part of this query I still get error

`PREFIXwordnet:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/wordnet.owl#> 
SELECT ?pre 
WHERE {
 ?word wordnet:?pre ?subject 
 {SELECT DISTINCT ?word WHERE { 
 ?word wordnet:?pre ?otherword 
 ?otherword wordnet:?pred ?word 
 wordnet:?pred ?ObjectSomeValuesFrom ?pre 
} }
}`

Comment: the same holds for `?%s` - whatever `nameWord` is, this will lead to a SPARQL variable. What would be the goal of this query?

Comment: maybe you do not understand, but `?` denotes the start of a variable, `wordnet:` denotes the start of a URI. You can't mix both. I don't know what your query is supposed to do ...  especially the query in your comment is far from being legal SPARQL syntax, Where are the dots between the triple patterns? What is the goal of the subquery?

Comment: I have several queries that, in theory, should return contradictions from the ontology.

Comment: I don't know SPARQL at all... I just have some queres that shoud work

Comment: ok, but what should people do now? I mean, SPARQL syntax is online as well as tutorials. Look at the query in your comment. Even the inner SELECT query is just useless, it's not legal SPARQL syntax: `SELECT DISTINCT ?word WHERE {   ?word wordnet:?pre ?otherword   ?otherword wordnet:?pred ?word   wordnet:?pred ?ObjectSomeValuesFrom ?pre  }` - no dots between triple patterns, then this odd `wordnet:?pred` and even more confusing one time another one `wordnet:?pre` - it should be clear to start from scratch

Comment: and what means, "should work" ? Who created the queries? And again, without saying what the query should do, impossible to help. I don't even know your data nor the expected result. Can you add this to the question maybe?

Comment: For now I don't have data. I don't know who created these queries... They are supposed to work with RDF ontology and return contradictions from the ontology. that's all I know... Anyway thank you for response!

Comment: do you have any guess what can mean ?%s in SPARQL query?

Comment: `%s` is most likely for string interpolation in Java. So, `?%s` will create a variable name, when you pass `var1` it will result in `?var1`, that's all. BUT: `wordnet:?pre` can't be correct. There is for sure no RDF predicate in the ontology

Comment: I agree that %s stands for some variable, thank you. you mean if I have RDF with predicate query can be applied?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I also don't know how to help here. I mean, you even don't have any data so far. So how would anybody write a query for unknown data? The query has to reflect the structure of the data.

Comment: and I still don't get where exactly you have problem with your initial query in the question? Where exactly do you execute the query and how?

Comment: I use Protege. Tab window -> SPARQL query. Before executing the query I open in Protege some owl ontology from internet. Protege returns errors when I try to run the query

Comment: which string exactly do you put into the query tab?

Comment: this query: 

`PREFIX wordnet:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/wordnet.owl#>  
SELECT ?word  
WHERE {  
 ?Box wordnet:?pre ?subject  
 { SELECT DISTINCT ?pre WHERE {  
 ?word wordnet:?pre ?otherword   
} } 
 OPTIONAL { ?Box wordnet:?pre ?word} 
} `

Comment: Box is name of the entity from owl ontoglogy

Comment: `PREFIX wordnet:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/wordnet.owl#>   SELECT ?word   WHERE {    ?Box ?pre ?subject    { SELECT DISTINCT ?pre WHERE {    ?word ?pre ?otherword    } }   OPTIONAL { ?Box ?pre ?word}  }` - clearly this doesn't do anything specific

Comment: damt it! it suppoused to retenr A if Concept A is expressed by a word or phrase X, which is already reserved in the ontology to reflect the basic concept B. At the same time, concepts A and B have incompatible semantics.

Comment: sorry, impossible to help without seing the data and expected result. That is too abstract what you're saying. The same would be the case for any SQL query request, when not knowing the database schema. All I can say is to have a look at your data and then you have to specify either subject , predicate or object position in the triple patterns of the query.

Comment: I get my RDF from `http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/demo/` I enter a text in the window `The box is red. The box is green`. Then choose Output format RDF/XML, enter CAPTHA, hit Read it! So I get RDF-outout. I save it on my computer as my_file.owl. Open Protege, load my_file.owl, got to tab SPARQL-query. There I need to run a query that will return BOX because there's contradiction: BOX CAN'T BE RED AND GREEN AT THE SAME TIME. I hope, it clears a little what kind of a query I nead